# pykeyboard not importing from its module

Tags: python, import, package, raspbian

I am having an issue where the package `PyKeyboard` is unable to be imported from its library `pykeyboard`. When executing the following:
`from pykeyboard import PyKeyboard`
I am subjected to the following  error:

```
  File "relay.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pykeyboard import PyKeyboard
ImportError: cannot import name 'PyKeyboard' from 'pykeyboard' (/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pykeyboard/__init__.py)
```

Uninstalling the package, running from root, or reinstalling Python lead me to no avail at all. I am at a brick wall.

Comment: @python_user https://pypi.org/project/PyUserInput/

Comment: @GonçaloPeres龚燿禄 yes, installed via root and uninstalled and reinstalled again. No difference. It was working for me until I used launcher shell, where it used a different iteration of Python so I had to install it for that vesion as well. Thats where things went haywire

Comment: @python_user not that I know of.

Comment: @GonçaloPeres龚燿禄 I do not have multiple virtual environments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the dependencies are installed. Considering that you are using [PyUserInput 0.1.11](https://pypi.org/project/PyUserInput/) ([as you said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67343351/pykeyboard-not-importing-from-its-module#comment119033277_67343351))

> Depending on your platform, you will need the following python modules
> for PyUserInput to function:
>
> - Linux - Xlib
> - Mac - Quartz, AppKit
> - Windows - pywin32, pyHook

If you are using Windows, for installing [`pywin32`](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) run

```
pip install pywin32
```

And for [`pyHook`](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook) make sure to install your system's version. [Here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook) you'll find both 64 and 32. Note that for [whl files](https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing.html) one may need to install wheel, as

```
pip install wheel
```

And then

```
wheel install file_name.whl
```

When the dependencies are installed, install the package with

```
pip install PyUserInput
```

Comment: Edit: following your steps and reinstalling PyUserinput solved my problem! thanks

Comment: PyUserInput says of itsef:
`Deprecated
Please use Pynput instead.`  And, of course, Pynput doesn't help with the problem.